# System configuration problem

Tags: installation, configuration

I'm using ubuntu on my computer for the first time and I'm having problem with system configuration. First I choose language,then accept licence agreement, then choose where I am,then I choose keyboard layout and when I put information about who I am (name,username and log in automatically) I can't go forward??? I'm really confused,can anyone help me, what did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Blind shot: You need to enter a password even if you select automatic logins. It used to perform administrative task and as the key to encrypt sensible things.

Comment: Mark the answer as the best answer if your problem solved.